# How to change "step function" curve to smooth line using Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to Python and I am trying to make my charts look more smooth (less noisy) but the syntax that I am using is making my graphs look like step functions instead of a smooth curve.

I have researched and tried different ways of solving my issue (i.e., Rolling averages and interpolation) but I am running into many issues. I assume because it is because of the dataframe that I am calling.

If anyone can help that would be amazing!

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('2. TEDs.xlsx')
df1 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet 1')
df2 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet 2')

df1['Duration']=(df1.index.values)*5/60
df2['Duration']=(df2.index.values)*5/60

df1['B-SIDE AVERAGE'] = df1[['6 (U)','M','Y','Z','K','G','W','8 (U)','11 (U)','O','15 (U)','N','B','2 (U)','E','F','A','+','/','I','1 (U)']].mean(axis=1)
df2['B-SIDE AVERAGE'] = df2[['6 (O)','M','Y','Z','K','G','W','8 (O)','11 (O)','O','15 (O)','N','B','2 (O)','E','F','A','+','/','I','1 (O)']].mean(axis=1)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))
ax1.plot(df1['Duration'], df1['B-SIDE TRIM AVERAGE'], color = (1.,0.,0.), label = 'UNOCCUPIED')
ax1.plot(df2['Duration'], df2['B-SIDE TRIM AVERAGE'], color = (0.,0.,1.), label = 'OCCUPIED')
ax1.set_xlabel('Duration (min)')
ax1.set_xlim(0,max(df1['Duration']))
ax1.set_ylabel('Deg. C')
plt.title('Temperature Average', fontsize = 14)
ax1.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.817, 0.976), loc='center',
       ncol=2, mode="", borderaxespad=0.)
ax1.grid()
plt.show()
```

[Chart with step function like curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4YrY.png)

Comment: Both, rolling averages and spline interpolation are indeed possible solutions.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yes, I totally agree but I just cannot make it work. I am VERY novice to this software so I have been trying my hardest to make it work and I will continue. Knowing what syntax to use is my issue.

Comment: Usually the approach is not to reinvent the wheel, but rather to look how others have done it before. There should be plenty of questions with answers on SO already

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yes, I will continue to research. Thanks!

Comment: Another very nice solution is a fourier low pass filter.